# I want to make a popup window with an image

Tags: batch-file

I want to make it with a *.bat file, how would I do this? I haven't really that much experience with *.bat files, so I need help.

(I would be using this for several different things, I am not willing to explain what they are, but that is because I cannot share everything.)

Comment: Like I said, I would prefer to have an image popup, but I can do just plain text if I have to.

Comment: Can you tell us what you need it for?

Comment: I cannot, it is kinda confidential to my work.

Comment: All I can say is that I need to make a batch file that makes a popup window, the popup window will be for notifications.

Comment: I might be able to make it with C#, then run it with a batch file, much more simple that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to create a pop up message box in batch:

```
msg * your message
```

Comment: No probs, glad I could help :)

Comment: Huh? I've never seen such syntax, and it doesn't work on my Vista machine. In what environment does it work?

Comment: I'm running Win7 x64 but I have always known about this, not aware of it not working on a particular OS.

Comment: @dbenham See [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/termserv.php#Msg) It says TS but it obviously works elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple VBS script to create a text pop up.

**MsgBox.vbs**

```
MsgBox WScript.Arguments(0)
```

Then you can simply do something like the following from the command line or a batch file

```
msgbox "Hello world!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually made what I needed in Visual Studio C#, then converted it to Delphi, then made a *.exe